# Remove connecting areas of same color smaller than a given size from Image

Tags: python, image-processing, geojson

I have a fairly large (250000 x 250000 px) GeoTIFF containing black areas of interest on white background (white on black would also be possible). Due to I need my areas of interest as polygons in geojson format I run `gdal_polygonize.py`. Due to the large number of (small) black areas `gdal_polygonize.py` runs about a week on that large file.

In a post-process step, I delete all polygons (in the geojson) which are to small to contain a rectangle with given dimensions, e.g. 10 x 100px. 
To reduce the workload for `gdal_polygonize.py`

I'm looking for a way to get rid of those black areas in my geoTiff that are "small" before running `gdal_polygonize.py`. "Small" could be defined e.g. as "less than 1000 black pixels".

Any idea to delete areas of the same color up to a given area size in an image?

Comment: Perhaps `gdal_sieve` does what you want ?

Comment: That's it! Thank you!